# Crosstab table is not incrementing in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, pivot, pivot-table, crosstab

I have try to generated table from query using pivot. But when i tried to compile, the row is incremented but the colomn not increment. I have try to generated the query to pivot table in adf, and the colomn is generated. This is my code:

```
<band height="303">
        <crosstab>
            <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="499" height="200" uuid="77f9d29c-5ef4-4cd8-8b35-c18e7a70831d"/>
            <rowGroup name="KOMPETENSI1" width="60">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{KOMPETENSI}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="9cebd928-d666-4221-99bf-ef5a6d917ab1"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{KOMPETENSI1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="2975a46b-27d0-4e72-aec0-9e4116cee446"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total KOMPETENSI1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <columnGroup name="TAHUN1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{TAHUN}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="8f43f54c-6de3-407b-b36f-34d3b559cc02"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TAHUN1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="6a20de24-7100-495f-9e85-c82d9924e69a"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total TAHUN1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <columnGroup name="JOB1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{JOB}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="18d62d4b-e2e9-4ecf-b68a-f97f436d571d"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{JOB1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="68d57411-4634-4383-aaa6-a7f6f4fa8c8f"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total JOB1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <columnGroup name="JENJAB1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{JENJAB}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="a46d026b-99c0-44c1-a7f0-b1b1deb8ea45"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{JENJAB1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="2b6f1d48-25aa-4345-9725-6065a99c72cc"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total JENJAB1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <measure name="LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.String">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{LEVEL_JOB}]]></measureExpression>
            </measure>
            <measure name="LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.String">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI}]]></measureExpression>
            </measure>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CD">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="8d786258-a3ba-447e-b7a6-d515b3b83495"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font size="5"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="a052bd65-583b-4e65-ba9c-fb705fa8762e"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font size="5"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="TAHUN1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="10f3a0a6-8da7-4eea-bd76-080ec3ac457d"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ff6b097f-377b-450d-9f31-c2d615c689f0"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="JOB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="d26f9674-e4c4-4ffb-8cc5-b4b83c2e5000"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="9cb43185-e1e8-42f9-8ba7-ec6b31a4f3f2"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="JENJAB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="b40177ac-bbc2-416e-969c-8f21007ee4b6"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="814d6eff-61a6-430c-a2bf-fa2a92467496"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="eedbded2-f179-4d9c-a38a-0e188854a3c4"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2fd20c2a-8472-41d9-bef1-aa5ae54c1332"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1" columnTotalGroup="TAHUN1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="524a4a98-6e1c-4d4b-974b-ce12dd00afd9"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7b5692a4-9bc7-4499-9c52-c3cac33ff921"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1" columnTotalGroup="JOB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="40ad1b84-ff41-46e1-b7c2-85a347a72ae3"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f2b21bb4-1125-4e3d-8476-dfbc846bd2f6"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1" columnTotalGroup="JENJAB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab 2_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ab621e9e-d237-46db-96a2-2203c54ef55a"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f806f467-6c8c-4dcb-a05c-f7f181b0b064"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
        </crosstab>
    </band>
```

This is my result pivot table:

[image]

I want the result like this:

[image]

If you see, the year of the table is not increment, how to fix it?

the query:

```
select CASE WHEN (JENJAB like 'SEVP') THEN '4' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'EVP') THEN '4' WHEN (JENJAB like 'SVP') THEN '4' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'SVP') THEN '4' WHEN (JENJAB like 'AVP') THEN '3' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'AVP') THEN '2' END AS LEVEL_JOB, kompetensi, 
    level_kompetensi, tahun, job, jenjab from OL_ASSESSMENT_RESULT 
    where tahun in (select tahun from ( select distinct tahun  
    from OL_ASSESSMENT_RESULT order by tahun desc)  
    where ROWNUM <=3 ) and npp = $P{npp}
```

The result of query:

[image]

Comment: hard to see something wrong with the crosstab code, double check your query.

Comment: @PetterFriberg i used the same query, and i have chacked the query but there is no different with adf application. i still confuse

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the crosstab.. (its not easy since i can't test), it need to be the data arriving... you have it summary band now correct?, you do not have a detail in jrxml correct?... if so it must be the query, remove param in query and test with a query you are sure... if you use in application remember to compile to jasper